# Magnific Popup issue with mixitup dynamic images

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-isotope, magnific-popup, mixitup

i just setup isotope manually into my website after that i dynamic it with the help of  get_terms and get_ther_terms condition here is the full code

```
     <div class="main_page">

<div class="portfolio_section">

          <div class="controls">
       <button type="button" class="control" data-filter="all">All</button>

        <?php

          $cat_list = get_terms('filters');

          foreach ($cat_list as $cat) :
          ?>
    <button type="button" class="control" data-filter=".<?php echo $cat->slug;?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></button>


      <?php endforeach; ?>


     </div>

   <div class="container pasresnt">

     <?php
         $mixitup = new WP_Query(array(
             'post_type' => 'portfolio',
             'posts_per_page' => -1,
         ));

     ?>
   
        <?php while ($mixitup->have_posts()) : $mixitup->the_post() ; ?>

<div class="mix <?php

           $cat_slug = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'filters');
           foreach ($cat_slug as $cat_sl) {
            echo $cat_sl->slug;
           }

           ?>">



            <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?> </a>


         </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
         <div class="mix green">

      <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mahi.jpg"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mahi.jpg"

alt=""></a>

</div>

</div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Here is the highlights in normal static image popup come correctly with this code

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mahi.jpg"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mahi.jpg"

alt=""></a>
```

but in dynamic this  images popup doesn't work for me .the last static one is as example which is work perfectly  but this line code which is the images come from portfolio custom post options this  pop up not working

```
<a href="<?php echo $for_img; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?> </a>
```

`

Comment: Have you tried removing `target="_blank"` from the one that's not working?

Comment: yes i have tried http://postimg.cc/NymxMh7v

Comment: with this and without this target="_blank"  image popup not showing

Comment: this static code works  `   <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mahi.jpg"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mahi.jpg" alt=""></a>  `                                                                                                                                         but this work dosen't as i explained before `    <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?> </a>  `

Comment: Well `target`  is the only difference between them. What do you mean by "not working"? That doesn't tellus anything. Are you getting an error? Is it not showing at all? Is it opening in a separate tab?

Comment: interms of i  dynamically try to set a images everytime while i try to new post from my custom protfoilos .new images is display correctly but the popup is not showing when click on a images .issue is with the popup http://postimg.cc/HVgHhRFP

Comment: The popup looks like its working properly, the problem looks to be with finding the image. Did you make sure the `$for_img;` url is are correct?

Comment: yes this is placed as same link variable .but i think there is a alternative way to call the popup images .and this alternative way i am looking for

Comment: when i inspect i can see the image url not showing and it's show some broken link check this screenshot http://postimg.cc/gn2dp8kv

Comment: As you can see in the inspector, the URL is wrong - its looking for the image `<img width...>` which isn't even a URL. Magnific Popup us working correctly, the problem is with your code that gets the URL. You need to find the error in that code. Don't use `the_post_thumbnail` to get the URL.

Comment: what can i use instead of the_post_thumbnail  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `the_post_thumbnail` for the `href`. That outputs the html to display the image, but you only want the URL to put into the `href` attribute of your link, so use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` instead.

So instead of this:

```
<a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?> </a>
```

You should use this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-small'); ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-small'); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'the_thumbnail_url' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\reels\wp-content\themes\mohi\portfolio.php on line 56

Comment: @jishan I'd just spotted a typo and fixed it just before your comment - it was an extra space in the `get_the_thumbnail_url` function name... can you try the edited code above ?

Comment: i fixed it but it called undefined function http://postimg.cc/r0nBCnM0

Comment: Oops! It should be `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` like I have said in the explanation, not `get_the_thumbnail_url`. Can you try that again  now:)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. Don't forget you can accept the answer if worked for you :) It marks it as resolved and lets others know it could help them too. And we both get a few rep points for the effort :)

Comment: yeah of course                               i must do it

Comment: actually i don't know how to resolve this issue on stackoverflow this is first time i got solved a problem here